# Testing Post request in Jersey Test Framework

Tags: java, rest, junit, jersey-test-framework

I am trying to write a test case in Jersey Test Framework for an authentication service as shown below:

Service code:

```
@Path("/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AuthenticationServices {
    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    public Response login(LoginRequest loginRequest, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
       ...... 
     }
```

Jerysey Test code:

```
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.AppDescriptor;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.WebAppDescriptor;
import com.vs.ant.sensordata.request.LoginRequest;

public class AuthenticationTest extends JerseyTest{
    @Override
    protected AppDescriptor  configure() {
        return new WebAppDescriptor.Builder("com.vs.ant.sensordata.services")
                                .contextPath("anttailbigdata")
                                .build();
    }

    @Test
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public void testLogin() throws JSONException,URISyntaxException {
        WebResource webResource = client().resource("http://localhost:8082/");
        String path = "SensorData/a/users/login";
        LoginRequest loginReq = new LoginRequest();
        loginReq.setUserId("admin");
        loginReq.setPassword("a");
        Entity<LoginRequest> loginEntity = Entity.entity(loginReq, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        ClientResponse resp = webResource.path(path).post(ClientResponse.class, loginEntity);
    }
}
```

When trying to execute the above test, i am getting the below exception:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException:  
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class javax.ws.rs.client.Entity, and MIME media type, application/octet-stream, was not found
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.post(WebResource.java:251)
at com.vs.ant.sensordata.services.AuthenticationTest.testLogin(AuthenticationTest.java:37)
```

I am new to jersey test. Not sure y this is happening. Please help.

EDIT: added @consumes annotation above the method.

Comment: if it is a POST api you must be consuming JSON/XML using @Consume and add jersey-media-moxy dependency in pom.xml

Comment: Even after adding the @consumes, i am getting the same exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Jersey 1.x test, but `Entity` was only introduced in JAX-RS 2.x, i.e. Jersey 2.x. Jersey 1.x has no idea how to handle it.

Instead just post the object itself, *without* any wrapping `Entity`, and set it's content type through the `WebResource#type(..)` method.

```
LoginRequest loginReq = new LoginRequest();
loginReq.setUserId("admin");
loginReq.setPassword("a");
ClientResponse resp = webResource.path(path)
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .post(ClientResponse.class, loginReq);
```

As an aside, if you are using Jersey 1.x, then you should get rid of any JAX-RS 2.0 dependencies you have, so you don't get confused in what you're using.